# Practicality of Faraday door

Tags: electromagnetism, radiation

Building a Faraday bed enclosure..wanted to ask which style of door would you advise in terms of seal - hinge,magnetic,Velcro etc. Measurements of the door is 900*900

Comment: Setting aside the question of whether this serves any useful purpose... Look at the design of EMI test chambers. They have fairly complicated rf gaskets on the doors. A lot of their other design features may also apply to your project.

Comment: 900 of what?  mm?

Comment: You'll definitely need [something along these lines](https://www.mouser.com/Passive-Components/EMI-Filters-EMI-Suppression/EMI-Gaskets-Sheets-Absorbers-Shielding/_/N-bkrm8) along the edge.  They're typically used to shield against RF emissions from equipment chassis.

Comment: I'm concerned by the phrase 'Faraday bed'. Is this a bed, in a cage, for you to sleep in, away from all the harmful radio emissions? If so, a tinfoil hat will be just as effective, and a lot easier to make.

Comment: @Neil_UK LOL Yet another SE site where a `tinfoil hat` tag would be nice to have. As for the question, moving to [West Virginia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_National_Radio_Quiet_Zone) would be another easier option.

Comment: @Neil_UK beat me to the tinfoil hat comment :(

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter what the seal is mechanically, it has to be conductive.

The contact doesn't need to be continuous, it can leave non-conducting slots of length L. However, the seal will be effective only up to a frequencies much lower than 300 MHz/2L, where the slot becomes equal to half a wavelength. At that frequency, slot resonance may actually enhance the ability of signals to get into the box.

The standard solution in industry for openings of that size is to have a very heavy door and frame that won't distort with the pressure, and to have a comb of spring fingers to make electrical contact across the gap. Without the spring fingers, the length of the slot is the length of the door opening, and a 900mm slot would fail to keep out signals above roughly 150 MHz.

The problem of sealing a Faraday cage door is the mechanical problem of compressing springs strongly enough to provide good contact. Gold-plated springs and seating can help with conductivity enormously. Intermediate mechanical fastenings can help a lot, meaning you only need to keep pressure up over a shorter distance. However, a large number of separate latches or screws would be time-consuming to operate, and a multiple-point cam lock needs some precision to work well. You might like to think about a luggage clip every 150mm.

If you look at the door of a microwave oven, you'll notice there are no conductive springs there. That's because the seal only needs to work at one spot frequency, 2.45 GHz. The door seal is 'choked', it uses exactly one quarter wavelength of open circuit gap. That technique will not work for a wideband Faraday cage.

There are lots of materials you could think about using. One ideal might be a metal zip fastener, where the teeth were electrically connected by mesh. Wire wool would be cheap, fairly springy, leave very small slots, but after corrosion the contact resistance would be appalling, most contact materials are plated for good contact conductivity and control of corrosion. Perhaps you could have a line of PCB edge connectors, or 0.1" pin/sockets. Once you have enough of these in a row, the insertion force becomes unmanageable, and you need very good precision to maintain alignment.